# jeditable button styling

Tags: jquery, css, jeditable

How do I style the buttons generated by jeditable? I am styling the textarea like..

```
.dynform textarea {
    width:450px;
    max-width: 2450px;
    height:200px;
}
```

where .dynform is the cssclass parameter to jeditable.

But the button style don't seem to take effect.

```
.dynform input[type=button] {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd; background: #f6f6f6 url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_f6f6f6_1x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; font-weight: bold; color: #38385c;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jeditable creates nodes of type 'button' not 'input'

```
.dynform button {
 border: 1px solid #dddddd; background: #f6f6f6 url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_f6f6f6_1x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; font-weight: bold; color: #38385c;
}
```